# Updating a properties files using "sed" for a complex string

Tags: linux, sed

I am trying to do an automated build.  There is a properties file in the format

```
#gpudb.conf

license_key =
```

I would like to write a wrapper script that I call the main script passing the license key as a command line option.

```
installer.sh <<license_key_value>>
```

I would like the `installer.sh` to replace the config file

```
sudo -H -u gpudb bash -c "sed -i 's/\(license_key\s*=\s*\).*/\1$1/' /opt/gpudb/core/etc/gpudb.conf"
```

$1 seems to work with simple string. If I have a large license file with lots of characters I get the following error.

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 40: unknown option to `s'
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to have the file with the line including "license_key = 
" and to add this  line to the file? Or does it need to change from time to time?

Comment: calling `bash` with an unsanitized input interpolation is dangerous, as it basically exposes you to arbitrary execution. consider I pass in following string to your script: `' | rm -rf /* '`.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the key may contain a forward slash which would break the sed command because it is using it as a delimiter. Probably you may find a delimiter that will never be part of a key and use it as the delimiter in sed? Like this:

```
sed 's_SEARCH_REPLACE_' # I'm _ as the delimiter
```

Otherwise I would recommend to use awk because it can handle fixed strings:

```
awk -v key="${key}" '/license_key/{print "license_key =", key;next}1' < file > file.tmp
mv file.tmp file
```